# Difference between "source-repository-package" and "local no-index repositories" in Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I know I can [add a local package to a cabal project](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/nix-local-build.html#developing-multiple-packages) by listing it in the [`packages:`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-packages) section of the [`cabal.project`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-projectindex.html#cap-cabal.project%20fields) file. The simplest example, which makes a project out of a single local package, is `packages: .`.

In `cabal.project` I can also add these two things:

- [`source-repository-package`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html?highlight=source-repository-package#specifying-packages-from-remote-version-control-locations) sections:

  ```
    source-repository-package
        type: git
        location: git@github.com:haskell-streaming/streaming.git
        tag: eb3073e6ada51b2bae82c15a9ef3a21ffa5f5529
  ```
- definitions of [local no-index repositories](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/installing-packages.html?highlight=source-repository-package#local-no-index-repositories)

  ```
    repository my-local-repository
        url: file+noindex:///home/zzz/no-index-repo-dir
  ```

It seems that both of them let me add packages to a project. What's the difference between the two?

(**Note**: this question is unrelated to the similarly-named [`source-repository:`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#pkg-section-source-repository-source-repository) field, which simply says which is the repository associated to the source code of a package.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only [`source-repository-package`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html?highlight=source-repository-package#specifying-packages-from-remote-version-control-locations) is actually adding a "local package" to your project. It behaves pretty much as listing a package's source folder in `packages:`, except that the source code is downloaded as needed. In particular, it will be re-downloaded when running `cabal build` after a `cabal clean`.

Because it's a local package in your project, other cabal projects are unaware of it. Adding it to other local projects requires recompiling it again.

---

Meanwhile, [local no-index package repositories](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/installing-packages.html?highlight=source-repository-package#local-no-index-repositories) are repositories in the sense of Hackage or Stackage, only in the local filesystem. They can be specified in both the `cabal.project` file of an individual project or in the global cabal configuration (`~/.cabal/config`).

Packages found in these repositories are not considered "local packages" of a project. Their libraries are compiled once and shared between all the projects which are aware of the package repository (which will be all projects, if the repository is listed in `~/.cabal/config`). And `cabal build` after `cabal clean` will not trigger a recompilation.

Comment: When working with local no-index repositories, we might need to use the `active-repositories:` field to control their relative priority with respect to Hackage https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-active-repositories Also, it's important to delete the generated cache file inside the repository after adding a new package's `.tar.gz`, otherwise it won't be seen by projects.

Comment: The situation may have changed with cabal-install 3.4 "compiled source-repository-package entries used in different projects are stored in the global nix-style store." https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5586 https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/6915 https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/6917