# How do I get cabal to use a local version of a package as a dependency for a Hackage package?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to install aeson on GHC 9.2.1. I first ran `cabal install --allow-newer --lib aeson`, which failed when it got to building attoparsec. It turns out this problem is [already fixed in their Git repo](https://github.com/haskell/attoparsec/commit/dc734e74816d60982cca30fc1986159d511ed582), but hasn't landed in a release on Hackage yet. I then did these steps to build a local version with the fix:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/haskell/attoparsec.git
cd attoparsec
cabal install --allow-newer --lib .
cd ..
```

That succeeded, but then when I did `cabal install --allow-newer --lib aeson` again, it tried to build attoparsec from Hackage again, and so failed again. How can I make cabal use what I just built and installed instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two main methods.

One is to create a [cabal](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html) [project](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/nix-local-build.html#developing-multiple-packages) that includes both the cloned version of attoparsec and the local packages that you are working on (packages that might depend on aeson). It could be as simple as

```
packages: attoparsec yourpackage
```

In fact, you don't even need to clone the repo, you could use the [`source-repository-package`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html#specifying-packages-from-remote-version-control-locations) field instead.

Because [local packages always take precedence over external ones](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/nix-local-build.html#local-versus-external-packages), the repo version will be chosen when resolving dependencies.

This approach works well but has the disadvantage that if you use the patched attoparsec in many different projects, you'll have to reference and re-compile it each time.

---

Another approach is to create a [local no-index package repository](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/installing-packages.html#local-no-index-repositories) in your machine, give it priority over stardard Hackage, and put attoparsec's [sdist tarball](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-sdist) there.

You need to declare the extra package repository using the `repository` field of your global cabal config (the path to the config is displayed in the last line of `cabal help`). By default, there's only Hackage:

```
repository hackage.haskell.org
   url: http://hackage.haskell.org/
```

To give the local package repository priority over Hackage, you need to use the [`active-repositories`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-active-repositories) field, either in your global Cabal config or in a `cabal.project` file.

The advantage of this method is that you don't need to create a Cabal project, and that the patched version of attoparsec will only be compiled once (as if it came from Hackage).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680185/difference-between-source-repository-package-and-local-no-index-repositories

Comment: I went with the second method and it worked for me, thanks. One caveat that might be worth mentioning: you need to delete noindex.cache from the local repository every time you add something to it.