# Cabal: only work with checked in libraries in project directory

Tags: haskell, cabal

I would like to download all the dependencies of my cabal project to my project directory/repository and force cabal to never use ~/.cabal/ and never download any new dependency from the internet. The downloaded libraries should be system independent (not include local paths etc.). Is this possible?

The idea behind this is, to copy the project directory to another (offline) system where the same ghc is installed and it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [cabal docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-project.html?highlight=active-repositories#cfg-field-active-repositories), you can set `active-repositories: none` in your `cabal.project` or cabal file to put cabal-install in offline mode.

Then, you could create a [cabal](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html) [project](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/nix-local-build.html#developing-multiple-packages) and try to make all the dependencies that don't come bundled with GHC itself [local packages](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/nix-local-build.html#local-versus-external-packages). Clone them in your project folder and add them to the [`packages:`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html#specifying-the-local-packages) section of `cabal.project`.

---

The problem with the above is that running `cabal clean` would require re-compiling *all* packages afterwards.

As an alternative, create a [local no-index package repository](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/installing-packages.html#local-no-index-repositories) in your offline machine, make it the only available package repository using [`active-repositories:`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-project.html#cfg-field-active-repositories), and put the [sdist tarballs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.6/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-sdist) of all your dependencies there.

That way the dependencies will only be compiled once.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69774372/1364288